# Extract different rows from 2 text files and append to new file

Tags: shell, powershell

I have 2 text files, one of them is called Invoice1.txt and the other Invoice2.txt. Both files are in the same format.

Invoice1.txt contains:

> H~30011000 ~More data ...
>
> L~13332 ~More Data...
>
> L~13332 ~more Data...

and Invoice2.txt contains:

> H~30011000 ~More data ...
>
> L~13332 ~More Data...
>
> L~13332 ~More Data...
>
> H~30022000 ~More Data...
>
> L~13999 ~More Data...
>
> L~13999 ~More Data...

Essentially what I am trying to do is create a new file which contains non-duplicate row data from both files as explained below. The last 3 lines from Invoice2.txt are NOT in Invoice1.txt so that would be appended to the new file.

My desired Output would be:

> H~30022000 ~More Data...
>
> L~13999 ~More Data...
>
> L~13999 ~More Data...

How would I write it with Powershell. Would I have to `get-content` for both .txt files and select the objects that are not equal?

```
$file1 = "C:\Invoice1.txt"
$file2 = "C:\Invoice2.txt"
$results = "C:\NonDuplicate.txt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** adapted to OPs preliminaries

```
$file1 = ".\Invoice1.txt"
$file2 = ".\Invoice2.txt"
$results = ".\NonDuplicate.txt"
$Content = Get-Content $File1 
Get-Content $File2 |
  ForEach { if ($Content -notcontains $_) {$_} }|
    Set-Content $Results
```

This is another step easier :

```
Get-Content $File2 | Where {$Content -notcontains $_}| Set-Content $Results
```

Output

```
> cat .\NonDuplicate.txt
    H~30022000 ~More Data...
    L~13999 ~More Data...
    L~13999 ~More Data...
```

Comment: Thanks! The output should only be the last 3 lines from Invoice2.txt though. So -unique would not work :( . It should be whatever row is not in both files.

Comment: Change script to meet your expectations.

Comment: Umm... this does not return the values from `$file1` that are unique... just the ones from `$File2`. The op sample data does not have any but the question refers to both files.

Comment: FYI You need to use @matt for me to see your response. From the question: _Essentially what I am trying to do is create a new file which contains non-duplicate row data __from both files__ as explained below._ Like I said the sample data does not account for that possibility but the OP did ask for it.

Comment: @matt see his first comment

Comment: While that is true it could be understood as supporting both our arguments but the text in the question is clear to me. Given the two input files  the result is the last 3 lines of invoice2 only because invoice1 has no unique lines of its own. If someone found this question, as asked, to fix their own issue your solution would be incorrect.

Comment: @matt you are right my unedited answer was the unique approach. The edits can still be seen.

Comment: I don't want to get it this much more but I am talking about your current solution and not your previous one. If there was a line in invoice1 that was unique to invoice1 it would not show in the output. You are only filtering invoice2

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve it . But I made a simple one for you and explained on each line how things are working.

Below is the script and screenshots for your reference.

```
# Taking input from both the files 
$file1= Get-Content E:\Source_Test\invoice1.txt 
$file2= Get-Content E:\Source_Test\invoice2.txt
# Ignoring the case sensitivity . So making it to lowercase. Parsing it to get non duplicates in each file and appendind the result to the file
($file1).tolower() |sort |  Get-Unique | Out-File E:\source_test\NonDuplicate.txt -Append -Force
($file2).tolower() |sort |  Get-Unique | Out-File E:\source_test\NonDuplicate.txt -Append -Force
# Getting the data from both the files and again taking the non-duplicates and finally storing in the file
$file3=Get-Content E:\Source_Test\NonDuplicate.txt
($file3).ToLower() | sort | Get-Unique | Out-File E:\Source_Test\nonduplicate.txt -Force
```

**Images:**

[image: Invoice 1]

[image: Invoice 2]

[image: Non-Duplicates]

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi Thanks! The .toLower() is not necessary as the row data will be exactly the same all the time, also it does not need to be sorted. But that wouldn't matter. Anyways, the output should only be the last 3 lines from Invoice2.txt because they are NOT in Invoice1.txt.

Comment: Thats great then. :)

Comment: If you have at least v3 you can just do `Sort-Object -Unique`. You should read the OPs post again since this does not do what was requested. He wants the lines unique to both files. You are just scrubbing duplicate lines.

Comment: @Matt: May I know which line is returning duplicate values?The non-duplicate.txt is only returning unique values. Secondly, if you go through the post , I have only mentioned **tolower()** which is not required for his puspose. Other than that all the things are proper. Could you please go through it once more instead of pointing things like this. It is very rude and offensive .

Comment: Your output does not match that of the OP which he has stated in his first comment. He is not looking for lines unique in the combination of both files. He is looking for lines that _do not appear in both_. As for the rest of your code all I was trying to do is show where it could be made more efficient. This is neither rude nor offensive. It is a fellow coder trying to help you.

Comment: Fine. I understood the intention of being more productive . But I only tried to give an approach. Anyways, fine mate.

Answer (score 1):

Other proposal, which works regardless of how many files you have

```
$dirwithfile="C:\temp\test"

#extract list of files
$listfile=gci "$dirwithfile\Invoice*.txt" -file

#for every file, get content and extract only rows which not exist in other content file, write result into file NonDuplicate.txt
$listfile |  
    %{ $filename=$_.Name;  gc $_ | where {$row=$_; ($listfile | where Name -ne $filename | gc) -notcontains $row   } } |
        out-file "$dirwithfile\NonDuplicate.txt" -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are small then `Compare-Object` would be great for this.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file2) -PassThru | 
    Set-Content $results
```

This would literally give you the results you asked for with minor coding. It has issues with blank lines it seems so you might need to post process some of those out depending on what you exactly want for results. `-PassThru` is there so the custom objects that `Compare-Object` typically makes are avoided. Instead the lines that do not match are pushed thru. You use temp variables for the files contents but why bother if you are only going to use them once.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $file1) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file2) -PassThru | 
Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
```

If your files are larger then this might not be efficient.